# Elixir/Phoneix - SFTPClient Connection Error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am going to integrate the SFTPClient library into `Docker`ized `Elixir/Phoenix` backend project for accessing the SFTP server.

Using FileZilla, it was working perfectly with the OpenSSH private key.

But using the library, it doesn't connect to the server and returns weird error messages.

```
options = %{
      host: "",
      port: ,
      user: "",
      password: "",
      private_key_path: "",
      connect_timeout: 60000,
    }

SFTPClient.connect(options)
```

Error messages:

```
protocol: String.Chars
```

```erlang
{:badmatch,
 {:error,
  {:asn1,
   {{:invalid_value, 5},
    [
      {:asn1rt_nif, :decode_ber_tlv, 1, [file: 'asn1rt_nif.erl', line: 85]},
      {:"PKCS-FRAME", :decode, 2, [file: 'PKCS-FRAME.erl', line: 155]},
      {:public_key, :der_decode, 2, [file: 'public_key.erl', line: 239]},
      {SFTPClient.KeyProvider, :decode_private_key, 2,
       [file: 'lib/sftp_client/key_provider.ex', line: 44]},
      {:ssh_auth, :get_public_key, 2, [file: 'ssh_auth.erl', line: 145]},
      {:ssh_connection_handler, :is_usable_user_pubkey, 2,
       [file: 'ssh_connection_handler.erl', line: 1793]},
      {:ssh_connection_handler, :"-init_ssh_record/4-lc$^0/1-0-", 2,
       [file: 'ssh_connection_handler.erl', line: 477]},
      {:ssh_connection_handler, :init_ssh_record, 4,
       [file: 'ssh_connection_handler.erl', line: 476]},
      {:ssh_connection_handler, :init, 1, [file: 'ssh_connection_handler.erl', line: 412]},
      {:ssh_connection_handler, :init_connection_handler, 3,
       [file: 'ssh_connection_handler.erl', line: 374]},
      {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 247]}
    ]}}}},
[
  {:public_key, :der_decode, 2, [file: 'public_key.erl', line: 243]},
  {SFTPClient.KeyProvider, :decode_private_key, 2,
   [file: 'lib/sftp_client/key_provider.ex', line: 44]},
  {:ssh_auth, :get_public_key, 2, [file: 'ssh_auth.erl', line: 145]},
  {:ssh_connection_handler, :is_usable_user_pubkey, 2,
   [file: 'ssh_connection_handler.erl', line: 1793]},
  {:ssh_connection_handler, :"-init_ssh_record/4-lc$^0/1-0-", 2,
   [file: 'ssh_connection_handler.erl', line: 477]},
  {:ssh_connection_handler, :init_ssh_record, 4, [file: 'ssh_connection_handler.erl', line: 476]},
  {:ssh_connection_handler, :init, 1, [file: 'ssh_connection_handler.erl', line: 412]},
  {:ssh_connection_handler, :init_connection_handler, 3,
   [file: 'ssh_connection_handler.erl', line: 374]},
  {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 247]}
]
```

**Answer:**
Referring to i22-digitalagentur/sftp_client#11, OpenSSH key won't work with the current library, so, I used command to convert the current OpenSSH key into PEM format.

```
ssh-keygen -p -N "" -m pem -f ./key(=keypath)
```

Comment: The library is this: https://github.com/i22-digitalagentur/sftp_client ?

Comment: have you tried to deploy this on localhost without docker? It seems you might be missing some dependencies like openssl

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Yes, that's the library I used.

Comment: I found the reason while looking at the library source code. It was because, key file was in openssh format, although the library was using PEM format. After converting key file into PEM format, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for this dicsussion!!!

Comment: @EverestClimber I am positive this question _with_ an answer might be useful for future visitors. So please put “key file was in openssh format, although the library was using PEM format. After converting key file into PEM format, it worked perfectly” as an answer and mark it as accepte$d. Thanks you!

Comment: @EverestClimber - you could also include a code snippet you used to convert the key.

Comment: Sure, I will do.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin
Just posted an answer by hoping that it would be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: @EverestClimber great, thanks, let’s contribute to making this world a bit better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out the way of fixing the current SFTPClient library issue.

Referring to https://github.com/i22-digitalagentur/sftp_client/issues/11, OpenSSH key won't work with the current library, so, I used command to convert the current OpenSSH key into PEM format.

```
ssh-keygen -p -N "" -m pem -f ./key(=keypath)
```